# I am trying to update status to twitter using twitter4j but it does not work

Tags: twitter4j

I succeeded to get every credentials(`Oauth_token,Oauth_verifier`).
With it, I tried to post a text to twitter account, but it always fail with error message "**No authentication challenges found**"

I found some solution like

**"Check the time zone automatically",
"import latest twitter4j library" etc..**

but after check it, still not work.

Is there anyone can show me the way.

code is like below

```
    public static void updateStatus(final String pOauth_token,final String pOauth_verifier) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            try {
                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory();
                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(pOauth_token,pOauth_verifier);

                Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Cdef.consumerKey, Cdef.consumerSecret);
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                if (twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled()) {                   
                    Log.e("btnTwSend","인증값을 셋팅하였고 API를 호출합니다.");
                    Status status = twitter.updateStatus(Cdef.sendText + " #" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    Log.e("btnTwSend","status:" + status.getText());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("btnTwSend",e.toString());
            }
        };
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "No authentication challenges found"

I think you are missing Access token secret in your code. That is why you are getting this exception.

**Try following :**

```
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder;
Configuration configuration;

    // Set the proper configuration parameters
    configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    configurationBuilder
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    configurationBuilder
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

    // Access token 
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    // Access token secret
    configurationBuilder
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    // Get the configuration object based on the params
    configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
    // Pass it to twitter factory to get the proprt twitter instance.
    twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();

    // use this instance to update
    twitter.updateStatus("Your status");
```

Comment: I certainly set the 4 key and that is follows : consumer : m0Ju0uzvuiFVZrZdXhBxpdId4 ,
tA8jaldE1lWy7D0YWlzXqJvgD5wkCv7PLUhYseiu8H2py53hOG

access :
HK2l8H2aCU46FXyW4InKrryq8LZ5kuvMLlla79Ng ,
2NSRIrqvSEVSm70o0ecKKnfKB6fZDDMIvUnMLjS1PsY

It's okay. because it is test account.
but not work...

Comment: I have a query. Can we please discuss at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50550/discussion-between-suhail-and-you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason.

I thought parameter named 'oauth_token' , 'oauth_verifier' is member of accesstoken, 
but it was not true.

I just had to pass one more way to get correct key.

and this way needs 'oauth_token' , 'oauth_verifier' to get accesstoken.

This code must add one more code below:

mAccessToken = mTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(REQUEST_TOKEN,OAUTH_VERIFIER);